# Proving that the space with norm; $\left\|x\right\|_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_i\right|^p\right)^{1/p}$ is separable

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, separable-spaces

Consider the normed space $\ell_p$ for $p\geq 1$ of infinity sequences {$x_k$} s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left|x_i\right|^p < \infty$ with norm defined as;

$\left\|x\right\|_p=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_i\right|^p\right)^{1/p}$

The question contains two parts, for the first part I have been able to complete by proving that $\left\|x\right\|_p$ is indeed a norm by applying Minkowski's Inequality for the triangle inequality which follows from duality using Holder's inequality (which follows from Young's inequality).

But now I have been asked to show that this normed space $\ell_p$ is also separable which I am stumped on. I know that the space contains infinity sequences {$x_k$} but why must every nonempty open subset of the space $\ell_p$ contains at least one element of the sequence?

Any help or hints greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about sequences with rational entries that are eventually $0?$

Comment: @zhw hmmm interesting, I will think more about this, can you elaborate?

Comment: @zhw. What do you mean by looking at these sequences. Are these an everywhere dense countable subset?

Comment: @ReginaldDick hmmm I unable to prove that it is but have no contradiction either

Comment: @RickOwens Do you know the Weierstrass approximation theorem? A corollary is that polynomials with rational coefficients, which is a countable set, is dense in $C([a,b]).$ Something very similar can be argued for $l^p.$ That's what my comment was meant to suggest.

Comment: @zhw this is very helpful, thanks!